# Oracle SQL Group BY Not pulling EMPLIDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run an Oracle query that returns all the emplids that do not contain a row with a.vc_plan_id containing one or many of the values: 'PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP'.

When I run the below query though it is still returning emplids that have rows with that value.  I tried using 'Group By', but it's not working.  Anyone know why?

```
select a.emplid
FROM ps_vc_plan_mem a, PSOPRDEFN b 
WHERE a.vc_plan_id NOT IN ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP') 
and b.OPRID like 'ZZ%'
and a.emplid = b.emplid
group by a.EMPLID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason would be that employees could have more than one value on different rows.  Using the structure of your query, you want a `having` clause rather than a `where`:

```
select a.emplid
from ps_vc_plan_mem a join
     PSOPRDEFN b 
     on a.emplid = b.emplid
where b.OPRID like 'ZZ%'
group by a.EMPLID
having sum(case when a.vc_plan_id IN ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows that *match* the forbidden conditions.  The `= 0` takes only those employee ids that have none of them.

Note:  This query can also be written using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery, but your original query uses a `group by`, so I'm preferring that solution.